# how does the Probabilistic Hough Transform compute the end points of lines?

Tags: computer-vision, hough-transform

According to [this OpenCV tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html), the Probabilistic Hough Transform directly returns the two endpoints of lines. I tried to read the paper, but did not understand how the end points of lines are being computed. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/47168821.pdf) gives a pretty straight-forward explanation regarding this (section 2.1). Basically, after a random pixel is selected from the input edge image, it is used to update a Hough accumulator. If this update results in a high enough vote for a given line `L` (*i.e* if a value in the accumulator matrix corresponding to `L` is higher than a threshold), then a search is performed by "walking" in both directions of `L` in order to find its extremes. This walk is interrupted if we reach an image border, or if a large enough gap is detected (`i.e` many pixels whose vote doesn't go to `L`).

Regarding the opencv implementation, you can see for example [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp) that it follows the given algorithm closely.